# distinct permutations of a list with repetitions

Tags: r, permutation

I want to write an R code to generate all distinct permutations of a list with a repeated characters in an efficient way.  For example,

```
x<-c(1,1,2,2,3,4);    
library(combinat);
unique(permn(x))
```

works, but it is very inefficient and dose not work if the length of the vector x is a bit longer. Does anybody know how to generate the unique permutations of above sequence in an efficient way?

Answer (score 2):

Permutations are unwieldy beasts. The number of permutations you get when selecting *r* objects from a set of *n* is

[image: perm]

When selecting all of them, meaning *r = n*, this reduces to

[image: permall]

For a set of 6 values, this is only 720, which isn't so impressive, but just look how quickly these numbers explode as you increase the size of the set:

```
data.frame(n=1:12,P=factorial(1:12));
##     n         P
## 1   1         1
## 2   2         2
## 3   3         6
## 4   4        24
## 5   5       120
## 6   6       720
## 7   7      5040
## 8   8     40320
## 9   9    362880
## 10 10   3628800
## 11 11  39916800
## 12 12 479001600
```

I doubt you're interested in building a list with 479,001,600 components!

---

Now, in your exact problem, you actually have what's called a [multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset), which means you're dealing with [multiset permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_of_multisets), which reduces the total number of permutations. You probably think this will save you from the unwieldy-ness. Well, think again!

The formula for multiset permutations is

[image: permmulti]

Starting with your example vector `x`, we have 180 (`factorial(6)/factorial(2)^2`), which again sounds wieldy, but let's try adding pairs to your vector and see what happens:

```
data.frame(m=paste('2 singles and',2:7,'pairs'),P=factorial(2+2*2:7)/factorial(2)^(2:7));
##                       m            P
## 1 2 singles and 2 pairs          180
## 2 2 singles and 3 pairs         5040
## 3 2 singles and 4 pairs       226800
## 4 2 singles and 5 pairs     14968800
## 5 2 singles and 6 pairs   1362160800
## 6 2 singles and 7 pairs 163459296000
```

I decided to stop at 7 pairs because beyond that R starts to do its scientific notation thing which is annoying to look at.

How about a couple of pairs and adding sets of 4? Let's try it.

```
data.frame(m=paste('2 pairs and',1:3,'quartets'),P=factorial(2*2+4*1:3)/(factorial(2)^2*factorial(4)^(1:3)));
##                        m         P
## 1 2 pairs and 1 quartets       420
## 2 2 pairs and 2 quartets    207900
## 3 2 pairs and 3 quartets 378378000
```

This time I had to stop at 3 to avoid scientific notation.

The point I'm trying to make with all of the above is that you can't go much beyond your current vector `x` and hope to generate all (multiset) permutations, using *any* algorithm; the numbers are just too big.

---

Despite all of the above, I did try to find a solution for your problem, which could be useful for a narrow range of multisets that are too large for `combinat::permn()`, but that are not too large to be completely impossible for any computer system to handle. I came up with the following recursive function (plus wrapper function):

```
gpermuteImpl <- function(uf) do.call(rbind,lapply(1:nrow(uf),function(r) { u <- uf$u[r]; if (uf$f[r] == 1L) if (nrow(uf) == 1L) return(u) else uf <- uf[-r,] else uf$f[r] <- uf$f[r]-1L; return(cbind(u,gpermuteImpl(uf))); }));
gpermute <- function(x) unname(gpermuteImpl(data.frame(u=unique(x),f=tabulate(x))));
```

This actually generates a matrix rather than a list. There's a lot of looping and `rbind()`ing and `cbind()`ing here, so it may not be the most efficient design possible, but it makes the code rather concise, since the `cbind()`ing automatically copies each selected value for all permutations that use that value in that position.

Here's a demo of it in action on your vector `x`:

```
x <- c(1,1,2,2,3,4);
gpermute(x);
##        [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
##   [1,]    1    1    2    2    3    4
##   [2,]    1    1    2    2    4    3
##   [3,]    1    1    2    3    2    4
##   [4,]    1    1    2    3    4    2
##   [5,]    1    1    2    4    2    3
##   [6,]    1    1    2    4    3    2
##   [7,]    1    1    3    2    2    4
##   [8,]    1    1    3    2    4    2
##   [9,]    1    1    3    4    2    2
##  [10,]    1    1    4    2    2    3
##  [11,]    1    1    4    2    3    2
##  [12,]    1    1    4    3    2    2
##  [13,]    1    2    1    2    3    4
##  [14,]    1    2    1    2    4    3
##  [15,]    1    2    1    3    2    4
##  [16,]    1    2    1    3    4    2
##  [17,]    1    2    1    4    2    3
##  [18,]    1    2    1    4    3    2
##  [19,]    1    2    2    1    3    4
##  [20,]    1    2    2    1    4    3
##  [21,]    1    2    2    3    1    4
##  [22,]    1    2    2    3    4    1
##  [23,]    1    2    2    4    1    3
##  [24,]    1    2    2    4    3    1
##  [25,]    1    2    3    1    2    4
##  [26,]    1    2    3    1    4    2
##  [27,]    1    2    3    2    1    4
##  [28,]    1    2    3    2    4    1
##  [29,]    1    2    3    4    1    2
##  [30,]    1    2    3    4    2    1
##  [31,]    1    2    4    1    2    3
##  [32,]    1    2    4    1    3    2
##  [33,]    1    2    4    2    1    3
##  [34,]    1    2    4    2    3    1
##  [35,]    1    2    4    3    1    2
##  [36,]    1    2    4    3    2    1
##  [37,]    1    3    1    2    2    4
##  [38,]    1    3    1    2    4    2
##  [39,]    1    3    1    4    2    2
##  [40,]    1    3    2    1    2    4
##  [41,]    1    3    2    1    4    2
##  [42,]    1    3    2    2    1    4
##  [43,]    1    3    2    2    4    1
##  [44,]    1    3    2    4    1    2
##  [45,]    1    3    2    4    2    1
##  [46,]    1    3    4    1    2    2
##  [47,]    1    3    4    2    1    2
##  [48,]    1    3    4    2    2    1
##  [49,]    1    4    1    2    2    3
##  [50,]    1    4    1    2    3    2
##  [51,]    1    4    1    3    2    2
##  [52,]    1    4    2    1    2    3
##  [53,]    1    4    2    1    3    2
##  [54,]    1    4    2    2    1    3
##  [55,]    1    4    2    2    3    1
##  [56,]    1    4    2    3    1    2
##  [57,]    1    4    2    3    2    1
##  [58,]    1    4    3    1    2    2
##  [59,]    1    4    3    2    1    2
##  [60,]    1    4    3    2    2    1
##  [61,]    2    1    1    2    3    4
##  [62,]    2    1    1    2    4    3
##  [63,]    2    1    1    3    2    4
##  [64,]    2    1    1    3    4    2
##  [65,]    2    1    1    4    2    3
##  [66,]    2    1    1    4    3    2
##  [67,]    2    1    2    1    3    4
##  [68,]    2    1    2    1    4    3
##  [69,]    2    1    2    3    1    4
##  [70,]    2    1    2    3    4    1
##  [71,]    2    1    2    4    1    3
##  [72,]    2    1    2    4    3    1
##  [73,]    2    1    3    1    2    4
##  [74,]    2    1    3    1    4    2
##  [75,]    2    1    3    2    1    4
##  [76,]    2    1    3    2    4    1
##  [77,]    2    1    3    4    1    2
##  [78,]    2    1    3    4    2    1
##  [79,]    2    1    4    1    2    3
##  [80,]    2    1    4    1    3    2
##  [81,]    2    1    4    2    1    3
##  [82,]    2    1    4    2    3    1
##  [83,]    2    1    4    3    1    2
##  [84,]    2    1    4    3    2    1
##  [85,]    2    2    1    1    3    4
##  [86,]    2    2    1    1    4    3
##  [87,]    2    2    1    3    1    4
##  [88,]    2    2    1    3    4    1
##  [89,]    2    2    1    4    1    3
##  [90,]    2    2    1    4    3    1
##  [91,]    2    2    3    1    1    4
##  [92,]    2    2    3    1    4    1
##  [93,]    2    2    3    4    1    1
##  [94,]    2    2    4    1    1    3
##  [95,]    2    2    4    1    3    1
##  [96,]    2    2    4    3    1    1
##  [97,]    2    3    1    1    2    4
##  [98,]    2    3    1    1    4    2
##  [99,]    2    3    1    2    1    4
## [100,]    2    3    1    2    4    1
## [101,]    2    3    1    4    1    2
## [102,]    2    3    1    4    2    1
## [103,]    2    3    2    1    1    4
## [104,]    2    3    2    1    4    1
## [105,]    2    3    2    4    1    1
## [106,]    2    3    4    1    1    2
## [107,]    2    3    4    1    2    1
## [108,]    2    3    4    2    1    1
## [109,]    2    4    1    1    2    3
## [110,]    2    4    1    1    3    2
## [111,]    2    4    1    2    1    3
## [112,]    2    4    1    2    3    1
## [113,]    2    4    1    3    1    2
## [114,]    2    4    1    3    2    1
## [115,]    2    4    2    1    1    3
## [116,]    2    4    2    1    3    1
## [117,]    2    4    2    3    1    1
## [118,]    2    4    3    1    1    2
## [119,]    2    4    3    1    2    1
## [120,]    2    4    3    2    1    1
## [121,]    3    1    1    2    2    4
## [122,]    3    1    1    2    4    2
## [123,]    3    1    1    4    2    2
## [124,]    3    1    2    1    2    4
## [125,]    3    1    2    1    4    2
## [126,]    3    1    2    2    1    4
## [127,]    3    1    2    2    4    1
## [128,]    3    1    2    4    1    2
## [129,]    3    1    2    4    2    1
## [130,]    3    1    4    1    2    2
## [131,]    3    1    4    2    1    2
## [132,]    3    1    4    2    2    1
## [133,]    3    2    1    1    2    4
## [134,]    3    2    1    1    4    2
## [135,]    3    2    1    2    1    4
## [136,]    3    2    1    2    4    1
## [137,]    3    2    1    4    1    2
## [138,]    3    2    1    4    2    1
## [139,]    3    2    2    1    1    4
## [140,]    3    2    2    1    4    1
## [141,]    3    2    2    4    1    1
## [142,]    3    2    4    1    1    2
## [143,]    3    2    4    1    2    1
## [144,]    3    2    4    2    1    1
## [145,]    3    4    1    1    2    2
## [146,]    3    4    1    2    1    2
## [147,]    3    4    1    2    2    1
## [148,]    3    4    2    1    1    2
## [149,]    3    4    2    1    2    1
## [150,]    3    4    2    2    1    1
## [151,]    4    1    1    2    2    3
## [152,]    4    1    1    2    3    2
## [153,]    4    1    1    3    2    2
## [154,]    4    1    2    1    2    3
## [155,]    4    1    2    1    3    2
## [156,]    4    1    2    2    1    3
## [157,]    4    1    2    2    3    1
## [158,]    4    1    2    3    1    2
## [159,]    4    1    2    3    2    1
## [160,]    4    1    3    1    2    2
## [161,]    4    1    3    2    1    2
## [162,]    4    1    3    2    2    1
## [163,]    4    2    1    1    2    3
## [164,]    4    2    1    1    3    2
## [165,]    4    2    1    2    1    3
## [166,]    4    2    1    2    3    1
## [167,]    4    2    1    3    1    2
## [168,]    4    2    1    3    2    1
## [169,]    4    2    2    1    1    3
## [170,]    4    2    2    1    3    1
## [171,]    4    2    2    3    1    1
## [172,]    4    2    3    1    1    2
## [173,]    4    2    3    1    2    1
## [174,]    4    2    3    2    1    1
## [175,]    4    3    1    1    2    2
## [176,]    4    3    1    2    1    2
## [177,]    4    3    1    2    2    1
## [178,]    4    3    2    1    1    2
## [179,]    4    3    2    1    2    1
## [180,]    4    3    2    2    1    1
```

We can prove that the result is identical to the result returned by `unique(permn(x))` with the following code, which unfortunately has to be slightly involved, because (1) we have a list vs. matrix type mismatch, and (2) the permutation order happens to be different between the two solutions.

```
library('combinat');
mcombinat <- do.call(rbind,unique(permn(x)));
mcombinat.sorted <- mcombinat[do.call(order,lapply(1:ncol(mcombinat),function(c) mcombinat[,c])),];
mbgoldst <- gpermute(x);
identical(mcombinat.sorted,mbgoldst);
## [1] TRUE
```

Finally, let me demonstrate the code on the 2 pairs and 2 quartets input:

```
x2 <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4);
system.time({ m <- gpermute(x2); });
##    user  system elapsed
##  36.547   0.000  36.593
head(m);
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
## [1,]    1    1    1    1    2    2    2    2    3     3     4     4
## [2,]    1    1    1    1    2    2    2    2    3     4     3     4
## [3,]    1    1    1    1    2    2    2    2    3     4     4     3
## [4,]    1    1    1    1    2    2    2    2    4     3     3     4
## [5,]    1    1    1    1    2    2    2    2    4     3     4     3
## [6,]    1    1    1    1    2    2    2    2    4     4     3     3
nrow(m);
## [1] 207900
```

So it took some time, but it got done. I tried running `unique(permn(x2))`, but it didn't finish after tens of minutes, and I think we can probably assume it would never finish, since it would have to generate 479,001,600 non-unique permutations, which `unique()` would then have the task of making unique. A quick calculation also suggests it would require about 46GB of RAM, which almost doubles the 24GB of RAM I have available on my system. That could also be a problem...

Comment: Thank you very much for your comprehensive explanations.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `RccpAlgos` package.

```
> library(RcppAlgos)
> x <- permuteGeneral(c(1,2,3,4), freqs = c(2,2,1,1))
> dim(x)
[1] 180   6
> head(x)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    1    2    2    3    4
[2,]    1    1    2    2    4    3
[3,]    1    1    2    3    2    4
[4,]    1    1    2    3    4    2
[5,]    1    1    2    4    2    3
[6,]    1    1    2    4    3    2
```

Comment: It should also be noted that for the example given above by @bgoldst (i.e. `x2 <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4)`, the result is obtained virtually instantly (i.e. `system.time(permuteGeneral(unique(x2), freqs = rle(x2)$lengths))` returns `elapsed  0.006`).

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if this is any faster, the bottleneck might be the high dimensionality of your problem as `x` gets any longer:

```
library(gtools)
x=c(1,1,2,2,3,4)
order = permutations(n=length(x), r=length(x))
x = matrix(x[order], ncol=6)
x = x[!duplicated(x), ]
```