# Are there algorithms for generating distinct permutations for not-necessarily distinct elements?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, permutation, multiset, heaps-algorithm

I have been reading about algorithms like [Steinhaus-Johnson-Trotter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhaus%E2%80%93Johnson%E2%80%93Trotter_algorithm) and [Heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap%27s_algorithm) to generate permutations, including Sedgewick’s paper on the subject.  But it seems these all work when all elements are distinct.  What happens if I have elements that can share values, and I want to filter out the portion of the `N!` exhaustive permutations that are observationally repeats?

I heard about the lexicographic approach.  There’s even two functions in the C++ library concerning them.  But what if the data is unordered; that is, I only have an equivalence predicate, not an ordering one.

Could those algorithms that Sedgewick looked at be adapted to skip over equivalent permutations (besides the first, of course)?

There is an existing query, “[distinct permutations of a list with repetitions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30963085/1010226),” that may come close, but its problem and solution set are in R, and not general.

Comment: It’s OK if I compare elements for equivalence as I go, or build a table of equivalence classes in advance.

Comment: I may be wrong here, but - Since the Steinhaus–Johnson–Trotter algorithm only swaps adjacent elements, maybe it's enough to skip swaps of equivalent values? This way we guarantee for each equivalence class the equivalent values are always in the same order

Comment: I had thoughts about that. It’s easy when testing when I’m bubbling an “e” to handle when I’m passing another “e.”  But I also need to skip the second “e” entirely when I loop through each letter at the top level. But I suspect that doesn’t work within the inner recursive calls.

Comment: Can't you just make an ordering predicate? given word ```"eef"``` can't you just label ```e_1, e_2, f_1``` and consider ```"e_1e_2f_1"``` but not ```"e_2e_1f_1"``` (since 2 occurs before 1 for class ```e```)